# Не работают label при динамическом добавлении input?

Tags: javascript, html, input, label

Почему-то не работают элементы label, добавляемые вместе с инпутами динамически (пробовал для инпутов типа radio и checkbox). При этом итоговая разметка аналогична разметке в "статическом" варианте (когда элементы сразу прописаны в HTML), но в статическом варианте всё работает (label кликабельны, и при клике на них выбирается соответствующий инпут).

Проблема наблюдается в Opera 11, в Firefox 38, Chrome 37.

Пытался не использовать при добавлении элементов innerHTML, работая с методами DOM - не помогло.

При правке через отладчик, допустим, атрибутов name, ничего не изменяется. При этом в "статическом" варианте всё работает даже если поменять через отладчик тип элементов с checkbox на radio, и сменить имена (сделав имя единым, чтобы связать радиопереключатели в группу). Что я делаю не правильно?

P.S. Атрибут for, разумеется, указан в обоих случаях. В JS использовал свойство htmlFor во втором варианте.

UPD: исходный код

```
function selectQuestion(index) {

   // Удаление старого содержимого...

   for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].answers.length; i++) {
      var ans = document.createElement('div')
      ans.className = 'answer'
      var str = questions[i].multiple == '1' ? 'ans' + (i+1) : 'ans'
      ans.innerHTML = '<input type="' + (questions[i].multiple == '1' ? 'checkbox' : 'radio') + '" name="' + str +'" />'
      ans.innerHTML += '<label for="' + str + '">' + questions[index].answers[i] +'</label>'
      document.getElementById('question_answers').appendChild(ans)
   }
   var answer = questions[index].selected
   if (answer != '') {
      var a = document.getElementById('question_answers').getElementsByTagName('input')
      for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].answers.length; i++) {
         if (answer.charAt(i) < a.length) a[parseInt(answer.charAt(i))-1].checked = true
      }
   }
}
```

UPD2: HTML код (при котором label не работают)

[image: скриншот окна Opera Dragonfly]

Comment: Добавил код, спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно W3Schools, [атрибуту for](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp) в качестве значения нужно передавать идентификатор (`id`) элемента.

Пример того, что даже в статичном варианте это не работает с `name` (браузер - Opera 30.0):

```html
<input type="radio" name="ans"/>
<label for="ans">Test</label>
```

А вариант с `id` работает:

```html
<input type="radio" id="ans"/>
<label for="ans">Test</label>
```

Упрощенный (для теста) JS-код для проверки работоспособности динамически добавленных `<label>`. `<input>` имеют одно значение `name`, но разные `id`:

```js
var answers = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    var ans = document.createElement('div');
    ans.className = 'answer';
    var id = "ans" + i;
    ans.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" id="' + id + '" name="ans"/>';
    ans.innerHTML += '<label for="' + id + '">' + answers[i] + '</label>';
    document.getElementById('question_answers').appendChild(ans);
}
```

```html
<div id="question_answers"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать. Почему-то думал, что привязка по name.
Однако, в Opera 11 вариант с name статический всё-таки работал. Можете сами установить и проверить :)
Видимо, это как раз тот случай, когда браузер выполняет при загрузке некоторую не свойственную ему работу, корректируя ошибки разметки.

Comment: @Alex654 да я тоже так думал до сегодняшнего дня, скажем прямо :) Да, отходы от спецификации - это браузеры умеют. Иногда это идёт на пользу, иногда - нет.

Comment: К слову, это логично: у радиогруппы name общий, иначе она не будет работать как группа. Оставался один вариант - сделать по id, конечно же.